# Can lineary independent eigenvectors be made orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got confused when I saw the Wikipedia document about [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).

> If one of the eigenvalues $λ_i$ has more than one linearly independent eigenvectors (that is, the geometric multiplicity of $λ_i$ is greater than 1), then these eigenvectors for this eigenvalue $λ_i$ can be chosen to be mutually orthogonal; however, if two eigenvectors belong to two different eigenvalues, it may be impossible for them to be orthogonal to each other.

> The linearly independent eigenvectors $q_i$ with nonzero eigenvalues form an orthogonal basis (not necessarily orthonormal) for all possible products $Ax$, for $x ∈ \mathbb C^n$, which is the same as the image (or range) of the corresponding matrix transformation, and also the column space of the matrix $A$. The number of linearly independent eigenvectors $q_i$ with nonzero eigenvalues is equal to the rank of the matrix $A$.

The two paragraphs seem to tell different facts. Can I select eigenvectors that is orthogonal if the matrix is diagonalizable and eigenvalues aren't zero, even the matrix is not a normal? Perhaps, if it is chosen without distinguishing between eigenspaces, I don't know again what *not necesarily orthonormal* means.

Comment: I find the second paragraph confusing too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well spotted! This was an error in Wikipedia that was introduced only a couple of months ago by [this anonymous edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix&diff=prev&oldid=1124374832) (with the edit summary “Orthonormal means orthogonal and unitary. I want to emphasize that they are not orthonormal only due to not being unitary.”). I’ve reverted the edit. As the first paragraph states and the subsequent example in the article illustrates, the eigenvectors for different eigenvalues may not be orthogonal.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment so the answer can be improved? (In case it was an author of one of the incorrect answers I downvoted: I showed the same respect of commenting on those.)